# How to recode 0 in a column to the median of the column

Tags: r

Hi I have a column in a dataframe in R which consist of 0

```
Sample -
mdfam0
25870
28670
21345
85100
0
```

Its right skewed, and I want it to be replaced with the median value of the column.

I am learning to do Data Cleaning with R. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a data.frame:

```
x=data.frame("mdfam0"=c(25870,28670,21345,85100,0))
> x
  mdfam0
1  25870
2  28670
3  21345
4  85100
5      0
```

If you want all the 0s to be the median of the whole column, use

```
> x$mdfam0[x$mdfam0==0]=median(x$mdfam0) #wherever x$mdfam0 is 0, change that value to the median of x$mdfam0
> x
  mdfam0
1  25870
2  28670
3  21345
4  85100
5  25870
```

If, instead, you want all the 0s to be the median of all the numbers greater than 0, use

```
> x$mdfam0[x$mdfam0==0]=median(x$mdfam0[x$mdfam0>0]) #wherever x$mdfam0 is 0, change that value to the median of all numbers greater than 0
> x
  mdfam0
1  25870
2  28670
3  21345
4  85100
5  27270
```

Comment: Considering whether to include the 0s or not **is** important, since the median depends on how many elements are involved. BTW: I was writing the exact same answer.

Comment: Thanks @matt. However the column I am working on is a factor variable. The data set is about Chicago rent data.

Comment: Then just use 

    as.numeric(as.character(x$mdfam0))

Comment: I did this- MedIncome = as.numeric((Data_rent$mdfamy0))
it works. But now I can see N/A. So I want to replace the N/A values with median and then put it back in the original frame. 

cause I will be using this frame for the regression model.

Comment: You have to be really careful using as.numeric() on factors, because it will default to giving you the _number of the factor level_, and not its value. You have to use as.numeric(as.character()).

You can replace NA values by saying x$mdfam0[is.na(x$mdfam0)]=y

Comment: Matt you were absolutely right. It wasnt the actual value with my first code. Now I did this - 
MedIncome2 =  as.numeric(as.character(Data_rent$mdfamy0))

On execution it says- N/A introduced due to coercion (which should likely happen)

Now my orginal data Frame is called Data_rent. How do I replace the value of N/A's and put it back in Data_rent. 

Sorry about asking too many questions, I am just trying to learn.

Comment: >x$mdfam0=as.numeric(as.character(x$mdfam0))

>x$mdfam0[is.na(x$mdfam0)]=median(x$mdfam0[x$mdfam0>0])

>If that column is actually a factor, you should double check to make sure there aren't any other weird values in it. It sounds like it's supposed to be all numbers.

Comment: Its just all numbers @Matt

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, So i did this -

Data_rent$mdfamy0=as.numeric(as.character(Data_rent$mdfamy0))  - converting to numeric character back into the dataframe

Coercion takes place and N/A's are produced. 

Try to replace N/A's using this command-

Data_rent$mdfamy0[which(is.na(Data_rent$mdfamy0))] <- median(Data_rent$mdfamy0)

Executes no errors thrown, works well.

however when i perform this-

which(is.na(Data_rent$mdfamy0))
 [1] 280 407 417 443 474 478 488 489 500 599 671 672 687 748

it still shows N/A's. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Sample)

Sample[ , mdfam0 := {
  V = mdfam0
  idx = V == 0
  med = median(V[!idx])
  V[idx] = med
  V
}]
```

Or perhaps

```
Sample[mdfam0 == 0, mdfam0 := Sample[mdfam0 > 0, median(mdfam0)] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample$mdfam0[Sample$mdfam0==0] = median(Sample$mdfam0[Sample$mdfam0!=0])
```

EDIT:

The RHS: Stuff inside the square brackets helps extract the non-zero elements of the column. The `median` function is called to calculate the median of those elements.

The LHS: The stuff inside the square brackets helps isolate the 0s in the column.

Setting them equal sets replaces the 0s with the median.

Comment: Can you provide some commentary on what this code does?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `na.aggregate` from `zoo` and specify the `FUN` as `median`

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Sample = na.aggregate(replace(Sample, Sample == 0, NA), FUN = median))
#  Sample
#1 mdfam0
#2  25870
#3  28670
#4  21345
#5  85100
#6  28670
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample = data.frame("mdfam0" = c(25870, 28670, 21345, 85100, 0))
Sample %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(mdfam0 = ifelse(mdfam0 == 0, NA, mdfam0), 
                mdfam0 = ifelse(is.na(mdfam0), median(mdfam0, na.rm = TRUE), mdfam0))
```